Configuring filebeat logging
I am trying to configure the logs for filebeat, (according to the docs). But filebeat keeps producing JSON logs like this:
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T13:48:23.762-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).configure","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1058},"message":"Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T13:48:23.763-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).configure","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1066},"message":"Beat ID: 53b210b7-5e66-424a-853c-fb4886a25377","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T13:48:23.764-0800","log.logger":"seccomp","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/common/seccomp.loadFilter","file.name":"seccomp/seccomp.go","file.line":125},"message":"Syscall filter successfully installed","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
etc...

When what I want is a regular human-readable log file like this, which is supposed to be the default according to the docs.
2017-12-17T18:54:16.242-0500    INFO    [example]   logp/core_test.go:16    some message.

My problem is with the log files produced by filebeat, about filebeat. Not the application logs being imported. Application log ingestion works fine. It's just stupid that I have to keep piping the output of filebeat to jq to be able to get something readable. I can't find an option to configure the log format anywhere in the docs.
The fineprint:
This is what's in the filebeat.yaml, I've removed everything else for now.
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0640

This is the filebeat section from the docker compose file:
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.16.1
    container_name: filebeat
    user: root
    volumes:
      - filebeatdata:/usr/share/filebeat/data
      - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
    environment:
      - ELASTIC_HOST=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - KIBANA_HOST=http://kibana:5601
    command: ["--strict.perms=false"]
    depends_on:
     elasticsearch:
       condition: service_healthy

These are full logs from filebeat:
# cat /var/log/filebeat/*
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.495-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).configure","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1058},"message":"Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.495-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).configure","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1066},"message":"Beat ID: 53b210b7-5e66-424a-853c-fb4886a25377","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"seccomp","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/common/seccomp.loadFilter","file.name":"seccomp/seccomp.go","file.line":125},"message":"Syscall filter successfully installed","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).createBeater","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":570},"message":"Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 8.16.1","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).logSystemInfo","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1619},"message":"Beat info","service.name":"filebeat","system_info":{"beat":{"path":{"config":"/usr/share/filebeat","data":"/usr/share/filebeat/data","home":"/usr/share/filebeat","logs":"/usr/share/filebeat/logs"},"type":"filebeat","uuid":"53b210b7-5e66-424a-853c-fb4886a25377"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).logSystemInfo","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1628},"message":"Build info","service.name":"filebeat","system_info":{"build":{"commit":"f17e0828f1de9f1a256d3f520324fa6da53daee5","libbeat":"8.16.1","time":"2024-11-14T14:56:43.000Z","version":"8.16.1"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).logSystemInfo","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1631},"message":"Go runtime info","service.name":"filebeat","system_info":{"go":{"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":8,"version":"go1.22.9"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).logSystemInfo","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1637},"message":"Host info","service.name":"filebeat","system_info":{"host":{"architecture":"x86_64","native_architecture":"amd64","boot_time":"2024-10-31T12:43:42-07:00","containerized":false,"name":"2e11cf53b78d","ip":["127.0.0.1","172.24.0.5"],"kernel_version":"5.15.0-124-generic","mac":["02:42:ac:18:00:05"],"os":{"type":"linux","family":"debian","platform":"ubuntu","name":"Ubuntu","version":"24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)","major":24,"minor":4,"patch":1,"codename":"noble"},"timezone":"PST","timezone_offset_sec":-28800},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.496-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).logSystemInfo","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1666},"message":"Process info","service.name":"filebeat","system_info":{"process":{"capabilities":{"inheritable":null,"permitted":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"ambient":null},"cwd":"/usr/share/filebeat","exe":"/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat","name":"filebeat","pid":176,"ppid":23,"seccomp":{"mode":"filter","no_new_privs":true},"start_time":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.280-0800"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.497-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).createBeater","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":606},"message":"no outputs are defined, please define one under the output section","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.497-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.(*Beat).launch","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":713},"message":"filebeat stopped.","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-12-07T14:03:17.499-0800","log.origin":{"function":"github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/cmd/instance.handleError","file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1590},"message":"Exiting: no outputs are defined, please define one under the output section","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}


I don't think filebeat support any other format, those logs are in json so that. you can send them directly to elasticsearch for exemple and be red from there.
